# Landscape orientation on iPad on app launch

Tags: ipad, rotation, ios9, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm using `GPUImage` which has class for a preview image. The preview image has to be set to the screen orientation for it to output correctly. Therefore, I need to get the correct orientation on app launch. However, testing `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` always returns 0 (Unknown).

So I force the orientation like so in `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

and it works on the iPhone and iPad mini - when app is launched in landscape, the device detects that it isn't in Portrait and reorients itself to landscape. This then calls `viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator`
and the correct output is set for `GPUImage`'s preview.

However, in the larger iPad sizes, this does not occur. When the app is launched in Landscape, it thinks it's in Portrait and does not redraw to Landscape as it does in the iPad Mini or iPhone. No call is made to `viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator`. I know it's because iPad in Portrait or Landscape is considered the same orientation. Somehow I need the app to know it's in Landscape after it launches so it can call the rotation methods.

Any advice?

Comment: Did you ever managed to solve this issue?